# How do you get rid of hum in audio?

Tags: audio, noise, ground-loop

I built a circuit for a simple amplifier that can use both bluetooth or a 3.5mm connector. The problem is that I am getting noise when I use the bluetooth module. There is no noise when I use the 3.5mm connector or when I power the bluetooth module from a second power supply. This leads me to  believe that there is something with ground loop isolation, which is why I put a transformer in the circuit. This didn't work, and I do not understand what to do to fix it.

[image]

Ignore the fact that I went from stereo to mono and then use the rest of the circuit as though it were stereo. That is because I have only one transformer.

Comment: Can you better describe the "noise"?  Is it actually "hum" (50 or 60 or 100 or 120Hz constant tone from mains power)?

Comment: It's not a hum, more of random noise. I forgot to mention before that I am using a battery, so there is no mains hum etc

Comment: You don't show your RCA inputs Please revise your diagram if you want us to see what you are talking about. And you show two 0.1uF capacitors (C7 & C8) which are effectively shorting most of your audio to ground. So it seems possible that if you disconnect C7 and C8, you might have a much better signal-to-noise ratio.

Comment: It is not clear why you need the transformer at all?  Especially if you are powering the BT receiver from your own circuit. There is nothing that requires isolation there.

Comment: @RichardCrowley as I said before, everything works fine if I use two separate psu, so I you are right with not needing the transformer. I just need to somehow isolate the psu I suppose.

Comment: This is a deal-breaker question: What about the RCA connectors in your circuit? This is a very important question: Do C7 and C8 really short the audio to ground? What happens if you disconnect them? This is a trobule-shooting question: What happens if you connect only the Left or Right channel from the BT receiver? If you don't answer each of the questions it will be difficult to help you.

Comment: My observation is I see no hint that the signal GND is tied to earth GND, even through a 10K resistor. That means this circuit is 'floating' and has no earth GND ref, so it is subject to any local noise source. I think with all the bugs we see the OP should review his design and upgrade it to better standards.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure this is the source of your problem, but I do not see any decoupling caps around your linear voltage regulators.  The web abounds with stories about what happens when these capacitors are omitted: [Here](http://www.microchip.com/forums/m141474.aspx), [here](http://forum.allaboutcircuits.com/threads/7805-voltage-regulator-oscillation.31651/) & [here](http://www.electro-tech-online.com/threads/oscillating-volt-regulators.19602/) to list a few.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you should do a FFT and find the frequency of the hum. You can record the sound and do this digitally in MATLAB or on an oscilloscope using the FFT function. Look into an analog notch filter. It will require some extra hardware. If you can live with digital filtering that's the simplest method and you can get a higher order filter this way.